# Separating Tomcat and application log files

Tags: log4j

I am trying to separate the Tomcat and application logs. I want the Tomcat logs written to `catalina.out`, and the application logs written to an `app.log` file. However, my application logs are being written in both files catalina.out and app.log.

How can I instruct Tomcat to write the logs in separate files?

Comment: can you show your log4j.properties or log4j.xml?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the package of your application in log4j.xml or log4j.properties file to write the log messages to a separate file . You can see a sample log4j.xml that write log messages to a file appender based on the package `com.urpackage` . You can replace this with your application specific package .

You can learn more about this  [here](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat)

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="FileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="log_file.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{DATE} %-5p %-15c{1}: %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.urpackage" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="debug" />
</root>
```